# How to make datastore query faster without adding indices

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-python

I have the following simple query:

```
 client = datastore.Client('fmy_project')
 query = client.query(kind='kind1')
 query.add_filter('x', '=','y')
 for row in query.fetch():
   #process the row and save to file
```

It takes me for 100 rows 5 seconds to fetch the results when working from a local machine. This is awfully slow.

when i make strace on the python process i get many rows of:

> recvmsg(9, 0x7ffffc9ee9f0, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
>
> poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN}], 2, 200) = 0 (Timeout)

Is there a way to say datastore to fetch everything in one go or make a certain other optimization?

I googled and did not find any related option

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying it takes 5 seconds only to fetch? Without processing the data in your for loop at the end?

Generally it's better if you:

1. Fetch the data (*fetch returns a list of the data*)
2. Process the data on the returned list itself (*do not save to datastore within your loop!*)
3. Save multiple rows at once using "**put_multi**"

> ndb.put_multi(*dataList*)

See docs here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#batch_operations

Comment: Note that David is using the generic datastore client library, not the GAE-optimized `ndb` one (his code might not even be a GAE app or running inside the Google cloud).

Comment: That's correct. The processing is very minimal. I am just making a statistics with a defaultdict(int)  so really no overhead stats[row[0]]+=1